# How to classify using SVM classifier?

Tags: python, classification, svm

I'm trying to build svm classifier for my data set , i knew that svm classifier work with 2D array ,but this code doesn't work because the program see `newtemp2` as 3D array ,so i want to know what i must do for my data to use `svm classifier`.

```
    train_setfeat = []
    train_setlabel = []
    newtemp2=[]
    for vector in newtemp:
        newtemp2.append(np.reshape(vector, (431, 19)))
        #convert each vector to 2d array

    j = 0
    for vector in newtemp2:
        if j < 2100: # 70 % for train

            train_setfeat.append(vector)
            train_setlabel.append(classlabels[j])
            j += 1
        else:
            break


    test_setfeat = []
    test_setlabel = []
    j = 0
    for vector in newtemp2:
        if j < 2997 and j >= 2100:   #20 % for test
            test_setfeat.append(vector)
            test_setlabel.append(classlabels[j])
        if j>= 3000:
            break
        j += 1

    classifier1 = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
    classifier1.fit(train_setfeat, train_setlabel)
```

```
#sample of newtemp data
newtemp =[
    (0.05,0.0,0.0,0.02,0.0),
    (0.0,0.0,0.0,0.02,0.0),
    (0.05,0.0,0.0)]
```

Each sentence in data set represents as vector 0.0 if word is found ,else put the word's weight

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues in creating your training set using a combination of list and numpy arrays.

Try this part of the code, should solve your issue by replacing the line 3-5 with this code:

```
N=len(newtemp)
newtemp2=np.empty(N,431,19)
i=0;
for vector in newtemp:
    newtemp2[i,:]=np.reshape(vector, (431, 19)))
    i+=1
```

You can do the same thing for the rest of your code